# Can the HP granted from the Aid spell, be healed normally on a Simulacrum?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing, simulacrum

The [Aid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/aid) spell says:

> Each target's hit point maximum and current hit points increase by 5 for the duration

The [Simulacrum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) spell says:

> If the simulacrum is damaged, you can repair it in an alchemical laboratory, using rare herbs and minerals worth 100 gp per hit point it regains.

Technically, the simulacrum does not actually take any permanent damage if that damage is less than the HP granted by the Aid spell.
Can those HP created by the Aid spell be restored as normal via healing spells or by using HD on a short rest?

Do the HP granted by Aid  count as separate for healing purposes.

Comment: This seems like a pretty straightforward sub-question of the linked duplicate.

Comment: Not sure how this is a duplicate, nevermind a straightforward one.

Comment: Hmm, might have reopened it on my own, didn't know I had that power.

Comment: @SeriousBri That question asks if simulacra can be affected by healing magic and this question asks if simulacra can be affected by healing magic…

Comment: @SeriousBri Also a duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135911/62294)

Comment: No.  This is not a duplicate.  Im not asking if the simulacrum can be healed.  Im asking if th hp from the aid spell can be replenished. Its not the same thing.

Comment: The answer perfectly explains why this isn't a duplicate, the claims of it being a duplicate rely on self answering how the new hp works. An answer to this question has to cover that, and it isn't covered, or asked, in the other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

The Aid spell changes the Simulacrum's hit points; it doesn't change how it is damaged or how its damage can be restored.

While the Aid spell lasts, you can restore the extra in the laboratory but it would probably be easier just to cast Aid again once it expired.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be able to heal the damage during a short rest via spending hit dice? Crawford indicated it should work.

Comment: Why should it? Aid gives it more hp; it doesn't change the nature of its hp.

Comment: @AllanMills I just dropped ten hundo in bounties on why that doesn’t work.